# Need help with math and statistics.

Tags: probability, statistics

The world population is ~7 billion

Social Classes:

- Top .001% is ~70,000
- Second .01% is ~700,000
- Next .1% is ~7 million
- Rest 99.9% is ~6,993,000,000 (billion)

The odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting 1 person from the `Top  grp` **is it approx: 1 in 100,000 meets?**

What are the odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting **2 people** from the `Top grp`? **is it: 1 in 100,000^2 or 1 in 10,000,000,000?**

What are the odds of 1 person in the `Rest grp` meeting **2 people** from the `Top grp` on the same year?

(Assuming in a lifetime of 100 years.)

Comment: @amWhy yes I edited the original question instead of asking a new question by mistake.

Comment: You can delete this post, then.

Comment: look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158936/what-is-the-probability-of-two-people-meeting?rq=1 :)

Comment: @Katy thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

First, $70,000/7,000,000,000$ $*$ $6,993,330,000/7,000,000,000$ does equal (approximately) $1$ in $100,000$. Second, both $1$ in $100,000^2$ and $1$ in $10,000,000,000$ are the same number, so it is both. As to the third question, one would need to know the number of times a particular person meets someone else in a year; I would estimate this at a hundred thousand times per year, which means that a normal person would have a $1$ in $100,000$ chance of meeting two people in the top social class in any particular year. Of course, all of this is assuming that no factors other than pure chance are involved; in many countries there are caste systems that separate the upper and lower classes.