# Probability of Two People Meeting Each Other?

Tags: probability

Recently, I came across this question [What is the probability of two people meeting?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158936/what-is-the-probability-of-two-people-meeting) :

- In the world, there are currently $k$ people (for the sake of this problem, we assume $k$ as fixed, i.e. no births or deaths)
- Within this world population, suppose there are two groups of people: Group A and Group B
- There are $a$ people in Group A and $b$ people in Group B
- In general, a person in the world is expected to meet $z$ people in their lifetime

**Question**:  What is the probability that a person from Group A will meet a person from Group B?

An answer was provided in this question, but I am trying to solve this problem using a different method:

- In this problem, we can consider an instance where Set $Z$ is entirely contained within Set $B$ - and Set $B$ is entirely contained within Set $Z$
- Thus, the probability of meeting all people in Group $B$ can be given as : $b/k$
- By extension, the probability of meeting no one from Group $B$ can be given as: $[1 - (b/k)]$
- The above was the probability of a single person from Group $A$ meeting all people from
  Group $B$ and the probability of a single person from Group $A$ meeting no people from
  Group $B$.  Since there are $z$ encounters, the formula needs to be modified:

$$[1 - (b/k)]^z$$

Thus, would be the probability of person from Group $A$ meeting at least one person from Group $B$ can be given as:

$$1 - [1 - (b/k)]^z$$

And finally, since there are $a$ people in Group A, the formula needs to be modified one final time:

$$a * [1 - [1 - (b/k)]^z] $$

**Is this logic correct?**

Thanks!

- **Note:** It is not specified, but I am assuming that people in Group $A$ meeting with other people in Group $A$ are not being considered in $Z$
- **Note:** It was not specified in the question, but I am not sure if it is possible for the a person from Group $A$ to meet a  person from Group $B$ multiple times - i.e. is it $z$ unique encounters?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not correct, firstly it should be $k-1$ in the denominator throughout, since a person can't meet themselves, but there is a more serious problem, which is that a person also can't meet the same person twice, so the probability skews slightly towards either group $B$ or $A$ depending on how many of each has been met so far. You could theoretically adjust for that and instead of having to the power of $z$ you'll have a product ($\Pi$) running over the number of people met so far, but this seems overly complicated, if you use the choose function, the problem becomes quite simple:

The probability of a given person in group $A$ meeting only people from group $A$ is given by

$$P(\mbox{only people from A)}= \frac{\binom{a-1}{z}}{\binom{k-1}{z}} $$

So

$$P(\mbox{a person from B})= 1- \frac{\binom{a-1}{z}}{\binom{k-1}{z}} $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It was not specified in the question, but I am not sure if it is possible for the a person from Group A
 to meet a person from Group B
 multiple times - i.e. is it z
 unique encounters?

Comment: Ah I see, if not, your approach works with the $k-1$ correction